# How can I make this background white and stop it being "light red" as some kind of default?

Tags: graphics

This

```
 Graphics[Square, Background -> Yellow]
```

yields what it should do, namely:

[image]

But when I try to change the background to white, by going

```
Graphics[Square, Background -> White]
```

I get this:

[image]

Argh! How can I make the background *really* white? Note that the problem also occurs when I specify white using RGBColor.

Comment: The red reflects an error not an issue with the background. Square is not a graphics primitive. What you want is `Graphics[{Yellow, Rectangle[]}]`
? Or if you really want to change the colour of the background: `Graphics[{Yellow, Triangle[]}, Background -> Red]`

Comment: FWIW, `Square` means this: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Square.html

Comment: Look at the Tooltip as you mouse over your output; also look at the error indication on the output cell bracket; and the message box when you click on the `+` sign at the top of the output cell bracket.

Answer (score 1):

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thin], White, Rectangle[]}]
```

[image]